# Prettier replaces single quote character with &quot; when used inside double quotes | Angular .html files

Tags: html, angular, eslint, prettier, eslintrc

I have applied angular-eslint in my angular package. I have also added prettier configurations.
The prettier is changing the single quotation mark to &quote; symbol.

How can I fix that

The code before lint:

```
 <div
      [id]="field?.tempId"
      style="width: 100%; height: '400px'"
    ></div>
```

the code after lint

```
style="width: 100%; height: &quot;400px&quot;"
```

I have tried to change the parser for html files
currently it is structured as bellow

```
{
      "files": [
        "*.html"
      ],
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended",
        "prettier"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/template/eqeqeq": ["off"],
        "@angular-eslint/template/banana-in-box" : [ "error" ],
        "@angular-eslint/template/no-negated-async": ["off"]
      },
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": [
          "tsconfig.json"
        ],
        "extends": ["plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"],
        "rules": {
          "max-len": ["error", { "code": 140 }]
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Prettier through an Angular CLI project, you can also set Prettier options directly in your angular.json file under the "projects"

```js
"projects": {
  "your-project-name": {
      "lint-fix": {
        "options": {
          "lintFilePatterns": [
            "src/**/*.html"
          ],
          "fix": true
        }
      }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the override prop in this way:

```json
{
  "files": ["*.html"],
  ...
  "parserOptions": {
    ...
  },
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": "*.html",
      "options": {
        "parser": "angular",
        "printWidth": 140,
        "singleQuote": true,
        "htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "ignore"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: An unhandled exception occurred: ESLint configuration in .eslintrc.json is invalid:
        - Unexpected top-level property "overrides[2].options".

See "C:\Users\MARIAP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-R4kqt6\angular-errors.log" for further details.

I get an error in this scenario.